# Returning a Mono/Flux in the lambda

Tags: java, lambda, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I am trying to create a lambda with the below code. Here I am calling an API (API gateway) which in turn calls *Second Lambda* that returns `"Second Lambda"` However, when I test it, it's giving below output
Doesn't lambda support reactive types as return type in the handler()? Is there any way to return the actual value without using the blocking call `block()`?

```
public class FirstLambda implements RequestHandler<Object, Mono<String>> {

    public Mono<String> handleRequest(final Object input, final Context context) {
        String output=null;

        Mono<String> m= WebClient.
                create()
                .get()
                .uri("https://api.amazonaws.com/dev")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class);

        m.subscribe(x-> System.out.println("inside the mono "+x.toString()));
        System.out.println("Exiting the block");

      
        return m;
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{
  "scanAvailable": true
}
```

**Expected OUTPUT**

```
Second Lambda
```

**Second Lambda**

```
public class SecondLambda implements RequestHandler<Object, String> {
    public String handleRequest(final Object input, final Context context) {
        return "Second Lambda";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, when I test it, it's giving below output

That's because you're not waiting for the `Mono` to complete before returning, and since the `RequestHandler` provides no special support for reactive types, it won't wait either.

> Doesn't lambda support reactive types as return type in the handler()?

Reactive return types aren't supported here in the way you're expecting - but there's also very little reason to use them in this scenario. The main purpose of a reactive framework is to use few threads for many non-blocking requests - but in this setup, your lambda will be run once per request (when the API endpoint is called through API gateway), so there's no advantage whatsoever.

You can still use `WebClient` of course, but in this scenario, the only sensible thing to do is to call `block()` on the WebClient result.

Comment: Got it thanks. If I need to anyways call block(), doing a blocking call to return the actual result. Does using Webclient server any better purpose then blocking libs like Feign or Apache HTTPClient? I have noticed the package size and the cold start time increases drastically in WebClient as opposed to HTTPClient and Feign

Comment: Nope, any HTTP client will work just as well. No advantage in using Webclient.

Comment: Thanks!! Any client you would recommend for production use? I could see feign, Apache client with some good features like retry, throttling etc. But they are increasing the cold start time. Jdks HTTPClient gives the least cold start but doesn't have production features like retry etc..